# NameError when calling a method

Tags: python, appium

I have two files :

One contains all my functions **funclib.py**

```
import os 
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import WebDriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains 
import time

        def deviceSelection():
            desired_caps = {}
            desired_caps['appium-version'] = '1.0'
            desired_caps['platformName'] = 'iOS'
            desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '8.2'
            desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'iPhone 6'
            desired_caps['app'] = os.path.abspath('/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testapp-bfpdodvceugohuaaiiukkrcsrdqh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/testapp.app')
            global wd
            wd = webdriver.Remote('http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
            wd.implicitly_wait(60)
```

And i have another file **scripts.py** which will call this function.

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
import sys
sys.path.append('/Users/admin/Desktop/Suite/Global Scripts/')
from funcLib import *

deviceSelection();

def firsttri():
    wd.find_element_by_name("Accept").click()
    time.sleep(5)   
    wd.find_element_by_name("Sign In").click()
    time.sleep(5)
    wd.find_element_by_name("Need help?").click()
    time.sleep(5)
    wd.find_element_by_name("Close").click()
    time.sleep(5)


firsttri();
```

When I execute scripts.py, I am getting an error

```
 wd.find_element_by_name("Accept").click()
NameError: global name 'wd' is not defined
```

Not sure why. Can any one help me ?

Comment: wd is only locally defined, not globally. When deviceSelection() finishes, wd no longer exists.

Comment: Suggested reading: python tutorial on [Global and Local variables](http://www.python-course.eu/global_vs_local_variables.php)

Comment: @Stiffo : I have declared wd as global variable. But still getting same error

Comment: I'm not sure it would work that way. Return it to the global scope instead with return wd, and then in when calling deviceSelection() instead write wd = deviceSelection()

Answer (score 1):

You're a bit confused both on how scoping works in Python here.

When you call `deviceSelection()` it's not creating a `wd` that's `global` within the `scripts.py` file, it's global within the `funclib.py` file, and that's why you can't call it.

There are ways to arrange it so the global usage would work, but they're messy and you shouldn't. Instead you should remove the use of `global` and `return` the `wd` object instead.

```
def deviceSelection():
    desired_caps = {}
    desired_caps['appium-version'] = '1.0'
    desired_caps['platformName'] = 'iOS'
    desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '8.2'
    desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'iPhone 6'
    desired_caps['app'] = os.path.abspath('/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testapp-bfpdodvceugohuaaiiukkrcsrdqh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/testapp.app')
    wd = webdriver.Remote('http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
    wd.implicitly_wait(60)
    return wd
```

Because then you can just set `wd` within `scripts.py` itself.

```
wd = deviceSelection()
```

In general it's recommended that you use `return` statements rather than `global` to pass variables from one namespace to another because it's cleaner and more explicit, and it avoids confusing cases like this.

Comment: @remyathomas Glad it helped. Remember to upvote useful answers and mark whatever answer was most helpful as "accepted".